# Pattern matching in long text string

Tags: c

I wrote this code and it works in some cases. Sometimes, however, it fails, and I just can't see why. Can someone please help me spot the error?

It works for:
String: `ishanthakkar ishan`
patter: `ishan`

But it fails for:

String: `cpr ograming`
patter: `cpr`

Source:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <string.h>

int *compute_prefix_function(char *pattern, int psize)
{
    int k = -1;
    int i = 1;
    int *pi = malloc(sizeof(int)*psize);
    if (!pi)
        return NULL;

    pi[0] = k;
    for (i = 1; i < psize; i++) {
        while (k > -1 && pattern[k+1] != pattern[i])
            k = pi[k];
        if (pattern[i] == pattern[k+1])
            k++;
        pi[i] = k;
    }
    return pi;
}
```

// This function find matching string in O(n) time, so iterate through text string only once, when unmatching character found; it proceed with next character and start comparing with first character of string to be searched i.e pattern

```
int kmp(char *target, int tsize, char *pattern, int psize)
{
    int i;
    int *pi = compute_prefix_function(pattern, psize);
    int k = -1;
    if (!pi)
        return -1;

    for (i = 0; i < tsize; i++) {
        while (k > -1 && pattern[k+1] != target[i])
            k = pi[k];
        if (target[i] == pattern[k+1])
            k++;

        if (k == psize - 1) {
            free(pi);
            return i-k;
        }
    }

    free(pi);
    return -1;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    char target[200];
    char *ch = target;
    char pattern[20];
    int i;

    printf("Enter the string: \n");
    fgets(target,100,stdin);

    printf("Enter the string to be matched: \n");
    fgets(pattern,20,stdin);

    i = kmp(target, strlen(target), pattern, strlen(pattern)); 
    if (i >= 0)
        printf("matched @: %s\n", ch + i);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try to indent code correctly - no need of extra spaces.

Comment: Can you comment your code so that the intent of the various pieces is clear?  A function like `kmp()` is not part of the standard computing lexicon as far as I know, and you only state that the program does "pattern matching" without ever specifying what that means.  For all we know, the code could be correct as posted.

Comment: @ John: Sorry for inconvenience, I have added little description to understand the program.
Actually I have not coded entire program, so I also have some confusion!

Comment: @JohnZwinck: `kmp` is unambiguously Knuth-Morris-Pratt in string algorithms.

Comment: I have made some mistake in kmp() function.
Because it work well for text string & pattern like jiahkhan & jiah and return -1 for jiah & jiahkhan

Comment: Check it out for:
String : a ab  and 
String to be matched: a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *fgets* function reads and includes the ending CR (or CRLF) in the string.

Add a `chomp()` function, like

```
void chomp(char *s) {
    int n = strlen(s);
    while (n && (s[n-1]==10 || s[n-1]==13)) s[--n] = 0;
}
```

that removes any CR or LF at the end of the string.
Then `chomp()` *pattern* and *target* before calling `kmp()` (and after the `scanf()`)

```
chomp(target);
chomp(pattern);

i = kmp(target, strlen(target), pattern, strlen(pattern));
```

the program should behave better.

---

Note: `10` is `'\n'` (LF) and `13` is `'\r'` (CR)

Comment: I though this should work! 
I tried removing CR an LF but in this case it works for none of the case!

Comment: Did  you add the chomp function? Call it twice, for each variable, before the call to kmp? It works here...

Comment: Yes I did it in another way! Thanks buddy ring0, you was very near to my solution :)

Comment: @ring0 Those should be written as `'\n'` for LF and `'\r'` for CR, shouldn't they? Also the string terminator is more clearly written as `'\0'`.

Comment: @unwind Agreed for the CR/LF, 10 and 13 are not that famous. As for the `0` vs `'\0'`, I like to use `0` as many beginners see `'\0'` as a special character, while, in C, this is only the 1-byte integer value of zero. This helps to consider C from its basic principles.

Answer (score 1):

Got clue:

```
i = kmp(target, strlen(target), pattern, strlen(pattern));
```

was passing string length+1(for null character) so it was giving false result for some text string

```
i = kmp(target, strlen(target)-1, pattern, strlen(pattern)-1);
```

works for all cases!

Thanks to all of you for your time!